# SWT: Is it possible to move multiple widgets at the same time?

Tags: java, concurrency, swt

I successfully implement an animation for widget based on user desired position and duration. However, if I set two widgets to move, they can only animate one at a time. When I start moving widget A for 1000 ms. When its timing is 500ms, widget B should be start moving immediately for another 1000ms.

Can I possibly achieve this through SWT?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
beginMovingWidgetA();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        beginMovingWidgetB();
    }
}).start();
```

(This assumes that at least `beginMovingWidgetA` is an asynchronous method.)

Comment: Your suggestion is unmatched with the current implementation. Since they are generated. beginMovingWidgetA and beginMovingWidgetB can occur anywhere in the runtime, so it is not possible to change the code skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to schedule your animation task as `Runnable` on `Display`.

You may want to look at following existing libraries.

https://java.net/projects/timingframework

https://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home

Trident has good features and it has both `Swing` and `SWT` implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. The timingframework seems promising.